# Selenium click on a next-page link not loading the next page

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, web-crawler

I'm new to selenium and webscraping and I'm trying to get information from the link: https://www.carmudi.com.ph/cars/civic/distance:50km/?sort=suggested

Here's a snippet of the code I'm using:

```
while max_pages > 0:
                results.extend(extract_content(driver.page_source))
                next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="next-page"]')
                driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', next_page)
                max_pages -= 1
```

When I try to print results, I always get (max_pages) of the same results from page 1. The "Next page" button is visible in the page and when I try to find elements of the same class, it only shows 1 element. When I try getting the element by the exact xpath and performing the click action on it, it doesn't work as well. I enclosed it in a try-except block but there were no errors. Why might this be?

Comment: Why you use execute_script and don't just use next_page.click()

Comment: @EduardFlorinescu it's so that when I select a parent element of the link and do a click.

Answer (score 1):

You are making this more complicated than it needs to be. There's no point in using JS clicks here... just use the normal Selenium clicks.

```
while True:
    # do stuff on the page
    next = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[title='Next page']")
    if next
        next.click()
    else
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

replace:

```
next_page = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="next-page"]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', next_page)
```

with:

```
driver.execute_script('next = document.querySelector(".next-page"); next.click();')
```

If you try `next = document.querySelector(".next-page"); next.click();` in console you can see it works.

Comment: This does work. However, when looped over multiple (10 on my try) times, it doesn't load it by the same amount. (1 on my try)